# Php Goo.gl Url Shortener In Mysql_Fetch_Array

Tags: php, class, url-shortener, goo.gl

im trying to use Goo.gl class(url shortener) in my mysql query.

im getting 10 line from database via mysql_fetch_array; and need to create url for all lines.

as like this:

```
while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
$short_url = $googl->shorten("http://www.example.com/$f[news]"); 
echo $short_url; }
```

**but the script creates url, for only the first one.**

do you have any ide, how can i use this script for multiple url convert (to create url for all mysql_query line).

this is the script i use:

```
class Googl
{
    public $extended;
    private $target;
    private $apiKey;
    private $ch;

private static $buffer = array();

function __construct($apiKey = null) {
    # Extended output mode
    $extended = false;

    # Set Google Shortener API target
    $this->target = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?';

    # Set API key if available
    if ( $apiKey != null ) {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->target .= 'key='.$apiKey.'&';
    }

    # Initialize cURL
    $this->ch = curl_init();
    # Set our default target URL
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->target);
    # We don't want the return data to be directly outputted, so set RETURNTRANSFER to true
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
}

public function shorten($url, $extended = false) {

    # Check buffer
    if ( !$extended && !$this->extended && !empty(self::$buffer[$url]) ) {
        return self::$buffer[$url];
    }

    # Payload
    $data = array( 'longUrl' => $url );
    $data_string = '{ "longUrl": "'.$url.'" }';

    # Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    if ( $extended || $this->extended) {
        return json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch));
    } else {
        $ret = json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch))->id;
        self::$buffer[$url] = $ret;
        return $ret;
    }
}

public function expand($url, $extended = false) {
    # Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->target.'shortUrl='.$url);

    if ( $extended || $this->extended ) {
        return json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch));
    } else {
        return json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch))->longUrl;
    }
}

function __destruct() {
    # Close the curl handle
    curl_close($this->ch);
    # Nulling the curl handle
    $this->ch = null;
}
}$googl = new Googl();
```